# When changing typeahead tt-input background color tt-hint not shown

Tags: css, less, typeahead.js

By default ***tt-input*** is `transparent`, I want to change its background color when on focus to be `white`, but when I change the `color` the hint is not shown anymore because it's hidden by the `new color`.
How can it be changed?

Comment: Give background color along with some opacity. Complete solid color  will hide the hint as the hint is behind the text input.

Comment: I tried this option but then the background looks more gray than white.

Answer (score 2):

The `background-color: transparen` has been set as an inline style with javascript.
You should overwrite it by using `!important`.

for `<input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA">` you should use:

```
.typeahead.tt-input {
background-color: black !important;
}
```

Also see: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/677